# Disable .htaccess within .htaccess in a sub direcory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a /public folder in which there is an .htaccess file with a lot of rewrite rules.

We are making a new folder at /public/news, the rules of the first .htaccess file apply in this folder too and that's undesirable.

I don't have access to server's virtual host definition so my only other option is to put exceptions in every rewrite rule in the /public/.htaccess which is not preferable.

I was wondering if I could put a new .htaccess file in /public/news so that it will disable all the effects of the first .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answer above works, but I was hoping to find a way so that I don't have to modify /public/.htaccess

The solution was to put

```
 RewriteEngine off
```

In /public/news/.htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `/public/.htaccess` at the top (before other rules, after `RewriteEngine On`):

`RewriteRule ^news(.*)$ - [L]`

It will not rewrite anywhere because of the `-`, and the `[L]` will cause the current `.htaccess` to stop processing more rules (the `last` flag). Then the `/public/news/.htaccess` can take effect.

[Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)